# Python create dynamic select statement for mysql

Tags: python, mysql

In my MySQL database I have 10 tables.  Based on the user input, I want to select the rows from one of the table.  The user input is an image.  I am getting the number of columns and rows of pixels the image has and storing it in a variable.

```
rows,cols,channels = img.shape
w = int(cols)
h = int(rows)
l = w-10
m = w+10
p = h-10
q = h+10
area = w*h
```

the mysql tables are created basis the area of the image, and hence, depending on the area, I want to select the values from a specific table.

```
if (area < 110980):
        sql = "select * from adf1 where WIDTH between %s and %s and HEIGHT between %s and %s;",(l,m,p,q)
    elif (area < 182520):
        sql = "select * from adf2 where WIDTH between %s and %s and HEIGHT between %s and %s;",(l,m,p,q)
else:
        sql = "select * from adf10 where WIDTH between %s and %s and HEIGHT between %s and %s;",(l,m,p,q)
cur = mysql.connect().cursor()
cur.execute(sql)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects
```

However, when I pass on a single query within `cur.execute` I am able to retrieve the results.

```
cur.execute("select * from adf10 where WIDTH between %s and %s and HEIGHT between %s and %s;",(l,m,p,q))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

current your variable `sql` is tuple, so if you want to pass it as parameters to the `execute` you should use `*`

```
cur.execute(*sql)
```

you can read more in the doc [unpacking-argument-lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the document link, this works...will accept your answer in 5 mins

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

this should fix your problem. You need to use `%` not comma in the queries inside if else.

```
"select * from adf2 where WIDTH between %s and %s and HEIGHT between %s and %s;"%(l,m,p,q)
```